# Calico-node doesn't works

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I deployed the cluster with kubeadm. CRI is containerd and CNI is Calico.

I made 3 node cluster. While deploying Calico, two nodes are deployed well, but one is not.

For node which has problem, it shows calico-node is running status.

`kubectl describe node ubuntu`
[image: kubectl describe node ubuntu]

However, kubectl logs also doesn't give any WARNING or FATAL if I exec the calico-node pod to check the liveness.

`kubectl exec calico-node-qmhps -n calico-system -- /bin/calico-node -felix-ready`
[image]

This is the Whole Status of Calico CNI
[image]

Comment: If you do `kubectl describe pod calico-node-qmhps -n calico-system` and `kubectl describe pod calico-node-qmhps -n calico-typha-bd4557dbb-gj88p` are there any useful events? Does `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --output=wide` show that one node is causing problems for all pods, or just calico pods? Which documentation / steps are you following? If you're not already in there, you could also visit the Project Calico slack community https://slack.projectcalico.org/